# "FCM Error: Unexpected Response Code 400 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-volley

```
public class FcmNotificationSender {

String userFcmToken;
String title;
String body;
Context mContext;
Activity mActivity;

private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private final String postUrl = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
private final String fcmServerKey = "AAAAKRewSZs:APA91bEjPfRvwIFaM_XpIpccHoA-E_8jLtAu4MS9lnHmE2OEeFInj2awH4MFFVBEwNET9w63ihSBWB9y8btoNS2TGbZ8jtbQZ4CokLFj6lz131CZmxEXv2tSTU7tMCyPc7cN9-mYzaFH";


public FcmNotificationSender(String userFcmToken, String title, String body, Context mContext,Activity mActivity) {
    this.userFcmToken = userFcmToken;
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
}


public void sendNotification() {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        mainObj.put("to", userFcmToken);

        JSONObject notiObject = new JSONObject();
        notiObject.put("title", title);
        notiObject.put("body", body);
        notiObject.put("icon", "icon"); // Burayı isteğinize göre güncelleyebilirsiniz

        mainObj.put("notification", notiObject);


        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, postUrl, mainObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // Bildirim başarıyla gönderildiğinde yapılacak işlemler burada
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Bildirim gönderilirken bir hata oluştuğunda yapılacak işlemler burada
                Log.d("FCMWEONG", "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "key=" + fcmServerKey); // FCM sunucu anahtarını ekliyoruz
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(request);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
}
```

}

Hello,

I'm trying to send notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in my application, but I'm encountering an issue. I'm receiving the NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 400 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send error.
Areas where I'm facing the issue:

I have ensured that the userFcmToken value is set correctly.
I have checked the title and body values.
I'm certain that the fcmServerKey value is up-to-date.
I've performed the checks mentioned above, but I'm still encountering this error. Do you have any suggestions or experiences that might help me find the cause and solution for this error? It's worth mentioning that the error.getMessage() in the logcat is displaying a null value.

Any insights you can provide regarding the potential cause and resolution of this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.